# How to read/validate files from web address folder in c#

Tags: c#, web, webclient, directory, subdirectory

I have to read files from web address folder ...so have used below code for that ...i am not getting list of files...

```
string pathUser = "http:/mentpc.blob.core.windows.net/cents/201503";
string pathDownload = Path.Combine(pathUser, @"20150302110215315197/20150401100536436792");

WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(pathDownload);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
```

But i am getting exception saying ===>The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Please help me

Comment: you need to add an ending forward `/` from what it looks like at first glance also `http:/` should be `http://`

Comment: Are these two files or one file that you are trying to fetch in your sample code 20150302110215315197/20150401100536436792?

Comment: 20150302110215315197/20150401100536436792?...............thease are the subfoldrs

Answer (score 0):

What your error means, is that the Url is not Found. It should be pretty easy to debug and check your combined path in the debugger.

Firstly I don't think Path.Combine is the correct function to use for Url's. Path.Combine is used for Physical file paths. You should be using Uri for this.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http:/mentpc.blob.core.windows.net/cents/201503");
Uri downloadUri = new Uri(baseUri, "20150302110215315197/20150401100536436792");
```

Also, it looks like you are trying to access two files in the same url. If that is the case, you will need to change it and download one file at a time.

Comment: Actually there is one main folder named 201503 and others are subfolders .."20150302110215315197/20150401100536436792".............so inside all this we have list of files ...so how can read all folder and subfolders and again files inside that...

Comment: I have this web address path : ==>string pathUser = "http:/mentpc.blob.core.windows.net/cents/201503       ..........which has folders and subfolders inside that ... i have to read all files from that ..any idea

Comment: @ClarkMike I do not think you can do that. Firstly, a directory listing would need to be enabled on your web server, if you need to see a list of files. Secondly, the best way to achieve this would be to have a service (REST API) that gives you a list of files in a directory and then iterate through the returned list to download each file.